# Pdf of $Z=X/Y$ given a joint pdf

Tags: probability-theory

Find the p.d.f. of $z=x/y$

$f(x,y)= 2(x+y)$ for $0\le x\le y\le1$

I first did the simple way, transformation, then derivative, and multiply joint p.d.f by absolute value of the derivative. Then integral to get joint p.d.f. of $z$, but as I look and graph this, it does not seem quite right. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density $g$ of the ratio $Z=X/Y$ is given by the following integral: $$\int_{\mathbb R} |y|f(zy,y)\ \mathsf dy.\tag1 $$
Here $f(x,y)=2(x+y)\mathsf 1_{(0,y)}(x)\mathsf 1_{(x,1)}(y)$, so because $0<\frac xy < y$ we have
\begin{align}
f(zy,y)&=2y(1+z)\mathsf1_{(0,y)}(zy)\mathsf1_{(zy,1)}(y)\\
&=2y(1+z)\mathsf1_{(0,1)}(y)\mathsf1_{(0,1)}(z).
\end{align}
Computing $(1)$ then yields
\begin{align}
g(z) &= \int_0^1 |y|2y(1+z)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= 2(1+z)\int_0^1 y^2\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac23(1+z)\mathsf1_{(0,1)}(z).
\end{align}